# Need each daily report only show documents that were scanned after the last report run

Tags: sql, sas, data-integration

I want each daily report only show documents that were scanned after the last report was run. I don't want the report to be a running total of all previous documents.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE ARG_REPORT
 AS SELECT
   VID,
   LAST_NAME,
   FIRST_NAME,
   MI
FROM WORK.FINAL_RESULTS2;QUIT;
```

ARG_REPORT is the output, but gives all variables in the data. Need only today's scanned data. What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a column for the date of the report or scan? If so, I believe you could do something like:

```
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE ARG_REPORT
 AS SELECT
   VID,
   LAST_NAME,
   FIRST_NAME,
   MI
FROM WORK.FINAL_RESULTS2
WHERE REPORT_DATE >= GETDATE();
END
```

Comment: No I don't have the date and I think no need it. I need only today's scanned data. We can create a date maybe, don't know how to do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data that was already reported on in some fashion.  You could store it in a table (you could have a 'running total' report table that was indeed the running total, and when you generate your report get only new records by joining to that table).

If the `VID` field is something that you could use as a limit (select only VIDs that are larger than the largest VID in the previous report) then you could store that in a table (or in a macro variable - for example, if the last report is available to input, you could read it in, read the largest VID into a macro variable via `call symput`, and then limit your query that way).

Answer (score 0):

My reports shows like

```
             PROC EXPORT DATA= WORK.ARG_REPORT
        OUTFILE= "/dwdata/sas_data/ARG_REPORT_&numdate..csv" REPLACE;run;
```

Is there any way that I can compare the results with one day before. ARG_REPORT_&numdate-1, something like this. ?